# админка django добавление полей пользователя

Tags: django, django-admin

В стандартной модели пользователей django при создании выводятся только логин и пароль.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но после создания , если зайти в пользователя видны поля почта имя и фамилия. Как их сразу добавить в админке? чтобы при создании пользователя помимо полей что на скрине, выводились и имя фамилия ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант это чуть изменить UserCreationForm и UserAdmin.

В вашем приложении в файле `admin.py` добавьте следующий код

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _

admin.site.unregister(User)  # нужно что бы снять с регистрации модель User

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserCreationForm.Meta.model
        fields = '__all__'
        field_classes = UserCreationForm.Meta.field_classes


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {
            'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions'),
        }),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
```

Конкретно в `add_fieldsets` можно указать поля которые вам нужны.

Comment: Спасибо! то что надо